# $\sqrt{I}$ is the intersection of maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

> **Corollary 4.4.6** *Let $R$ be a f.g. $k$-algebra, $k$ field, and $I$ and ideal of $R$. Then $\sqrt{I}$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R$ containing $I$.*
>
> **Proof** $\quad$ We may assume that $I=0$. Clearly $\sqrt{0}$ is contained in every maximal ideal of $R$. Conversely, suppose $f \in R - \sqrt{0}$. Then $R_f \neq 0$. Let $\mathfrak{n}$ be a maximal ideal of $R_f$ and $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{n} \cap R$. Now, $R_f \big / \mathfrak{n}$ is a f.g. $k$-algebra and it is a field. Hence it is algebraic over $k$. But $R_f \big / \mathfrak{n} \simeq \left ( R \big / \mathfrak{m} \right )_f$. Hence $R \big / \mathfrak{m}$ is integral over $k$. This implies that $R \big / \mathfrak{m}$ is a field, *i.e.*, $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. Since $f \not \in \mathfrak{m}$, the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R$ is contained in $\sqrt{0}$. $\quad \square$

Here I am not getting, how does it follow $R_f/n\simeq (R/m)_f ?$ From theory of localisation, I know that, $R_f/m_f\simeq (R/m)_f$, but why $m_f=n ?$

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recall that the map $\mathfrak a\to \mathfrak a^c$ induces a bijection between prime ideals of $R_f$ and prime ideals of $R$ not containing $f$. The inverse is extension of ideals, which is what you want. See Proposition 6.7 [here](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013-c6.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @Pedro Tamaroff

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax, which is searchable, rather than an image, which is not, so that future users with similar questions will have an easier time finding this. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Thanks @HallaSurvivor . I shall keep it mind.